# Android Populate Spinner Dynamically

Tags: android, sql, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to populate Android spinner from the data I retrieve from database. Here is my SQL statement to retrieve the data:

```
private ArrayList<CategoryModel> catList = new ArrayList<CategoryModel>();
public ArrayList <CategoryModel> getAllCatName() {
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT categoryName FROM category";
        Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Grab Success");
        if (mCur.getCount() != 0) {
            if (mCur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    CategoryModel cm = new CategoryModel(); 
                    cm.setCategoryName((mCur.getString(mCur
                            .getColumnIndex("categoryName"))));

                    catList.add(cm);
                } while (mCur.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        return catList;
    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        throw mSQLException;
    }
}
```

And here is the code where I try to bind the data to the spinner:

```
    spinnerCat = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerCat);

    ArrayList<CategoryModel> cat_list = cc.getAllCatName();
    ArrayAdapter<CategoryModel> adapterFrom = new ArrayAdapter<CategoryModel>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cat_list) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            // Get item at position
            CategoryModel catModel = getItem(position);
            // Set textview's value with the category name
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setText(catModel.getCategoryName());

            return view;
        }
    };

    adapterFrom.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerCat.setAdapter(adapterFrom);
```

And in my entity class:

```
public String categoryName;
public String getCategoryName() {
    return categoryName;
}

public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
}
```

However, the problem now is the first item I retrieved seems working fine. But the following items in spinner appeared to be in this format `Entity.CategoryModel@61480167`. I wonder why is it so.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
DatabaseAdapter mDbHelper = new DatabaseAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.createDatabase();
    mDbHelper.open();
    CategoryController cc = new CategoryController(
            mDbHelper.open());

    Cursor cursor = cc.getAllCatName();
    if(cursor.getCount()>0){
           String[] from = new String[]{"categoryName"};
           // create an array of the display item we want to bind our data to
           int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
           SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
             cursor, from, to);
           mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
           spinnerCat.setAdapter(mAdapter);
          }
```

And my SQL statement method:

```
public Cursor getAllCatName() {
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT categoryName FROM category";
        Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Grab Success");
        if (mCur.getCount() != 0) {
            if (mCur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    CategoryModel cm = new CategoryModel(); 
                    cm.setCategoryName((mCur.getString(mCur
                            .getColumnIndex("categoryName"))));

                    catList.add(cm);
                } while (mCur.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        return mCur;
    } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
        throw mSQLException;
    }
}
```

And the new error message is column _id does not exist. I really have no idea why is it so as I never declared any _id anywhere.

Comment: Spinner Object created mulipal time in loop

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < cat_list.size(); i++) {     
        adapterFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cat_list.get(i).getCategoryName());
        adapterFrom.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerCat.setAdapter(adapterFrom);
    }   Problem in this line

Comment: Yeah but I not sure how to add an object into the spinner. Do you have any idea?

Comment: why don't u create a custom adapter

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar Could you please post it as answer? I really cannot read it from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> Temp = new ArrayList<String> ();
for (int i = 0; i < cat_list.size(); i++)
{
  Temp.add(cat_list.get(i).getCategoryName());
}
```

adapterFrom = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
                                          id of textview,Temp);
  adapterFrom.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_ite‌​m);
  spinnerCat.setAdapter(adapterFrom);

```
    spinnerCat.setOnItemSelectedListener
    (new OnItemSelectedListener() 
       {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+Temp.get(position),  
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by id of textView? I do not have a textview with me tho.

Comment: Thanks. It works! But do you have any ideas to get the position of selected items?

Comment: r u android developer my gmail id er.naveen.tamrakar@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a custom adapter because your array (cat_list) contains custom objects.

```
ArrayAdapter<CategoryModel> adapterFrom = new ArrayAdapter<CategoryModel>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cat_list) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Get item at position
        CategoryModel catModel = getItem(position);
        // Set textview's value with the category name
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

        textView.setText(catModel.getCategoryName());

        return view;
    }
};

adapterFrom.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerCat.setAdapter(adapterFrom);
```

Comment: But with these codes, it only return me one correct record. The rests of the records are like Entity.CategoryModel@41680648 and so on. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you sure all `cat_list`'s items return a proper String when you call `getCategoryName()` ? Please update your question with the code you are using now.

Comment: @user324977 I've edited the question. Could you please help me take a look?

Comment: @9Dollars99Cents dont use any custom ArrayAdapters,  use SimpleCursorAdapter instead

Comment: Sorry but how do I implement it according to my situation?

Comment: one minute googling http://techin-android.blogspot.com/2011/07/spinner-with-simplecursoradapter.html?m=1

Comment: But the return type of my SQL statement method is CategoryModel but not Cursor.

Comment: so remove it,  use a Cursor

Comment: Is there any alternate way to fix this? Cause I really not sure how to use a Cursor.

Comment: I read already but it keeps throwing me an error message and I;ve no idea why is it so. Check my edited portion.